# JavaScript Asynch Callback - How to await the endresult

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, async-await, setinterval

I have the following situation (see also jsFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/sMuWK/):

```
function CallBackStringHandler() {
    this.callback = function(){return null};
};

CallBackStringHandler.prototype.doTheMagic = function(callback) {
    var result = callback.call(this);
        if(result == null)
            alert("Nothing to handle yet...");
        else
            alert("End the result is: \n\n" + result);
};

function Action(){
    var result = null;
    var max = 10;
    var index = 0;
    var processor = setInterval(function(){
        if(index <= max){ //Processing step
            if(result == null)
                result = "" + index;
            else
                result += index;
            index++;
        } else { //Done
            clearInterval(processor);
            alert(result);
        }
    },10);
    return result;
};

function Run(){    
    var handler = new CallBackStringHandler();
    handler.doTheMagic(Action);
};

Run();
```

A script (a jQuery plugin) allows you to specify a callback that has to return a string.
This string will be handled by this script.

So far so good.

For the sake of performance and keeping my page responsive, I want to build this string in a multi-threaded way. Since this is not a web standard yet, I simulate this with the help of setInterval.

Now I know that the essence of doing things this way is not waiting for the results.

But I can't think of a way of keeping things responsive and fast and return the full result to the handler.

So the end result (in this example) should show: 012345678910.

Any help/clues would be appreciated.

Cheers, another nerd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to for a final answer I kinda resolved it this way ([fork here](http://jsfiddle.net/YkFDn/)):

```
function CallBackStringHandlerBy3rdParty() {};

CallBackStringHandlerBy3rdParty.prototype.doMagic = function(callback) {
    var result = callback.call(this);
    alert(result);
};

CallBackStringHandlerBy3rdParty.prototype.doMyOwnMagic = function(result) {
    if(result.isComplete) {
        this.doMagic(function(){return result.value;});
    } else {
        var that = this;
        result.value += 1;
        if(result.value < 10)
            setTimeout(function(){that.doMyOwnMagic(result);},10);      
        else {            
            result.isComplete = true;
            this.doMyOwnMagic(result);
        }
    }
};

function Run(){    
    var handler = new CallBackStringHandlerBy3rdParty();
    var result = {};
    result.value = 0;
    result.isComplete = false;
    handler.doMyOwnMagic(result);
};

Run();
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn it the other way around. `Action` is not a *callback*, it does not *consume* an asynchronous result but it *produces* it. `doTheMagic` on the other hand *is* the callback, as it *consumes* the result (by `alert`ing the result).

Thus, instead of passing `Action` as a "callback" to `doTheMagic`, you should be passing `doTheMagic` as a callback to `Action`.

```
function Run() {
    var handler = new CallBackStringHandler();
    Action(function(result) {
        handler.doTheMagic(result);
    });
    // or, alternatively: (only in modern browsers supporting Function.bind)
    Action(handler.doTheMagic.bind(handler));
};
```

Make `Action` accept a `callback` argument and call it when it's done. Finally, let `doTheMagic` just receive the `result`. I forked your fiddle, [have a look](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/zhSFa/)!

**Note:** You won't get multi-threading using `setInterval`, it will still run in the same browser thread as the rest of your script. If you *truly* need to do some serious heavy lifting, you may want to [use a web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers).

For most cases such as just concatenating a string like you're doing, this is overkill. Workers live in a completely separate environment and you can only communicate with them through messages, which adds quite a bit of complexity to your application. Make sure to do a good amount of testing and benchmarking before deciding that you really need a multi-threaded approach!

Comment: Hi Mattias, thank you for your quick response.
The CallBackStringHandler can be considered the 3rd party plugin which I don't want to touch. And at a certain point it does some 'magic' with the callback I provide (in this case immediately).
So my Action should return a complete result (string) and I want to do this in the async manner for the reasons I mentioned.
I like your example but I do not see how to use it in my scenario (which could be my shortcoming).

Comment: Well, if you can't touch the `CallBackStringHandler`, you could wrap the `result` in a function such as `return function() { return result; }` and pass that to `doTheMagic`. Surely, it will never have "nothing to handle" as you're only ever calling it *after* the results are in.

Comment: I will try that Mattias. Having some doubts still but if it works I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thank you so far!

Comment: You're welcome. Still, I think `doTheMagic` is not designed very well. It can't receive a result asynchronously, it would need to wrap the code using that result in a function and pass that function to the asynchronous producer as a callback. The only reason I see where it may benefit from accepting a `callback` argument is when it needs to retrieve a result depending on some parameters it gives. For example, if it would first calculate `foo` and `bar` internally, it'd retrieve the result with `callback(foo, bar)`. Still, that would be a *synchronous* result...

Comment: I agree with you on that part. But that's exactly the part I should not touch because it is a 3rd party thing. I might suggest a change though based on this page.

Comment: Ah, the joy of badly designed third-party libraries. Indeed, either you get those guys to adjust their design or you put another layer of indirection on top of their library (which makes that small callback function) to work around this flaw.

Comment: Yes, it is always possible to add another level of indirection... ;)